# How to remove vertical line in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to remove the vertical lines in vscode, In my VSCode I can see this yellow and red vertical lines, both are very disturbing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgrQh.png)

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, open your settings, search for 'Rulers'. Click on 'Edit in settings.json'. Remove any rulers you may have set.